# Cross Thread Error on comboBox1 in winforms C#/NET

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net

alredy a question out about this. but here comes another question little diffrent, and i cant find any awnsers to it!

```
String text = this.GuiThread(() => this.comboBox1.Text); 

 if (text == "this")
 {
   //do somthing spectacular!
 }
```

text is an empty variable or so..

Use of unassigned local variable. this is the ERROR i get..and iv tested all examples i can find here and at msdn.

im also having :

```
  public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        public static void GuiThread(this Control ctrl, Action action)
        {
            if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ctrl.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
            else
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
```

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code cannot compile.  The GuiThread returns void, you are trying to assign that to a string.  How you can get an exception is unguessable.  It needs to at least look like this:

```
public static class ControlExtensions {
    public static T GuiThread<T>(this Control ctrl, Func<T> action) {
        if (ctrl.InvokeRequired) {
            return (T)ctrl.Invoke(action);
        }
        else {
            return action();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't write code like this, the actual ComboBox text you'll read is pretty random since it can be obtain *while* the user is modifying it.  Give a thread the arguments it needs when you start it.  The BackgroundWorker class keeps you out of trouble.

Comment: that code just gave me 100k errors on my other GUI outputs                        this.GuiThread(() => this.listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.None);   is how i do it in rest of code

Comment: Did you consider *renaming* the function and keeping the original?

Comment: it did work then aperantly. alltough i cant quite understand what it does, and what it adds to my function.

Comment: Don't use code you don't understand.  Rip it all out and leave the threading for another day, when you're ready for it.